# Twitter API format "created_at" in PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I need a suggestion how to convert **Mon May 12 19:11:38 +0000 2014** into **2 minutes ago** or **10 minutes ago**.

My coding is something like this.

```
if(isset($tweets->statuses) && is_array($tweets->statuses)) {
            if(count($tweets->statuses)) {
                foreach($tweets->statuses as $tweet) { 
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $tweet->user->screen_name; 
                    echo "</td>"; 
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $tweet->text;
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $tweet->created_at;
                    echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
```

I've implemented something like this and I want to dig the `created_at` because it looks a bit weird. Anyway I've found many sources like [this](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1063). But that one is not what I want. What I want is to make it show like `2 days ago`, `10 days ago`, `yesterday`. Any idea?

Comment: @JohnConde hey, i have checked that but this is twitter. It is far different to that question.

Comment: It is **not** different. They both do the same thing. The Twitter part is irrelevant.

Comment: I will never know if I follow that question by the way. @JohnConde

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you are looking for.

```
    function timeSince($time) {

        $since = time() - strtotime($time);

        $string     = '';

        $chunks = array(
            array(60 * 60 * 24 * 365 , 'year'),
            array(60 * 60 * 24 * 30 , 'month'),
            array(60 * 60 * 24 * 7, 'week'),
            array(60 * 60 * 24 , 'day'),
            array(60 * 60 , 'hour'),
            array(60 , 'minute'),
            array(1 , 'second')
        );

        for ($i = 0, $j = count($chunks); $i < $j; $i++) {
            $seconds = $chunks[$i][0];
            $name = $chunks[$i][1];
            if (($count = floor($since / $seconds)) != 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        $string = ($count == 1) ? '1 ' . $name . ' ago' : $count . ' ' . $name . 's ago';

        return $string;

    }
```

Comment: @hey cmorrissey, would you let me know how to start to do with this code? I've the code and how to link from `$tweet->created_at` to `timeSince($time)`?

Comment: @Anthosiast `echo timeSince($tweet->created_at);`

Comment: `Call to undefined function timeSince()`. Doesn't work. What is this problem? I've put that function on the head tag as a javascript.

Comment: @Anthosiast this is not `js` this is `php` put it at the top of your document wrapped in `<?php    ?>` tags